# Difference between online and offline database in JDeveloper

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I am new to JDeveloper 12c, can anyone tell me what's the difference between online and offline database shown in "Initialize Business Components Project" in  the below screenshot.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Online - you are connecting to a database that is up and running.
Offline - allows you to define your Business Components against a database definition that is in JDeveloper and not a real live database. This allows you to work on ADF BC even when you don't have connection to your database.
(First you'll need to create some offline database objects though in JDeveloper).

Comment: Thanks @shay-shmeltzer for the clarification.